# Calculate Global (ECEF) coordinates of Observer

Tags: observational-astronomy, coordinate, artificial-satellite, satellite

I have the local coordinates of satellite and global coordinates of satellites. I want to calculate the observer position in global ([ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)) system.

How can I do this?

[image]

I also explain this question with more steps in following link.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383255/local-system-to-lat-lon

I am missing something, Can you please help me where I went wrong?

Comment: I'd guess that "local coordinates" means "coordinates in an observer based frame",  and "global coordinates" is perhaps an Earth centred, equatorial frame with x pointing at the the vernal equinox, or something.  I suspect this is mostly just  vector geometry, and a whole lot of cos, sin and arctan.  However the question is not very clear.  What exactly do you mean by "local" and "glcbal" coordinates.  What have you tried.  Finally Why do you want to do this.  If it is "homework" please let us know.  If its not, please tell us what your application is.

Comment: @JamesK I edit my question to identify better local and global.It is not an homework, I just want to develop an algorithm related this topic. For exp. my code find ECEF coordinates from local coordinates and vise versa, or calculate azimuth and elevation.